# PHP - $_ENV is not persisting

Tags: php

I want to share some information between all users of my PHP application. the closest thing i found to ASP.NET's Application, is

```
$_ENV
```

For some reason, what i set in that array, is not persisting through page refreshes.

Can someone give me some help?

Thanks

Comment: See for some alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475377/php-share-variable-among-different-users-sessions, http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/112975-variable-shared-users

Comment: `$_ENV` represents information about the environment that PHP is running on, i.e. the machine. It's not where you store application data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_ENV vars are only not changeable, they display information - I suggest using a database or a file. Databases are more secure if security is needed.

Answer (score 1):

`$_ENV` is an array with information about the environment PHP is running in. You cannot change it, it's purpose is to be read only.

To share (dynamic) information between visitors of your website, use some data storage like a database or textfiles.