# Ways users of a website can communicate

Tags: http, web

How can two users of a website communicate (share data)? I know of XMPP and accessing same data storage, sending data to server pushing data to users. How many other web technologies can achieve communication between users?

Comment: possibly a duplicate. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475377/php-share-variable-among-different-users-sessions