# How to call PHP session from another file.php

Tags: php

I'm trying to access session variables in file2.php from file1.php, but I'm getting the following error: undefined variable in file2.php.

How can I fix this?

This is `file1.php`:

```
<?php 
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-xsrf-token");

include "config.php";

$postjson = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$today = date('y-m-d H:i:s');

eif(isset($postjson['aks'])=="proses_login"){

 $logindata = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usuario 
    WHERE nomeUsuario='$postjson[nomeusuario]' AND senha='$postjson[Suasenha]'"));
if(isset($logindata['nomeUsuario'])==$postjson['nomeusuario']  AND ($logindata['senha'])==$postjson['Suasenha']){

$_SESSION['U']=$postjson['nomeusuario'];

$result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'msgs'=>'Bem Vindo '.$_SESSION['U']));
}else{
   $result = json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'msgs'=>'Nome do Usuario ou Senha incorrecta'));
}
  echo $result;
}

?>
```

and this is `file2.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$host = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=eventosonline";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";


    $con = new PDO($host, $usuario, $senha);
    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nomeUsuario ='".$_SESSION['U']." ' ");
    $sql->execute();
```

I tried to include `file1.php` but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3475398/222564

Comment: Sessions are on a per-user basis, not a per-page.  Any session variables set in one file should be accessible in another file as long it's accessed by the same user with the same browser.  What happens if you `print_r($_SESSION)` in file2.php?  Also, since you're preparing your query, why not USE the prepared query by binding the variable rather than including it right in your query string?  That'll save you from injection.

Comment: File 1 has some syntax errors which would prevent it from executing

Comment: I want to persist the username typed in the login form in this $_SESSION['U'] , I can access the variable only if I initialize the session variable outside of the if loop. example $_SESSION['U'] ='user name';
But the same example doesn't work if it's placed inside the if loop.
When I try to print to file2.php I get the same error but now in the file.php

Comment: Can you help me with some practical examples?

Comment: So, maybe the code isn't entering that `if` block, then? What debugging have you done?

Comment: print_r and echo

Comment: So...does the code enter that `if` block, or not, then? That was the main question. We can't run your code and we can't see the JSON data submitted so we can't predict exactly what the code will do, you need to tell us.

Comment: I have a login form in an ionic app that sends the 'username' for comparison with the data in mysql.
I can login, but I wanted to persist this 'username' data in this session $_SESSION ['U'] = $postjson ['username']; to later use it in file2.php.
I don't know if I'm creating the session well, but what I want is to persist the login information that the user types...

Comment: The code is entering the if block

Comment: If it enters the `if` block then it must set the session variable. So perhaps we go back to the earlier comments?

Comment: I'm calling file2.php on a page of my ionic app to fetch user details in mysql through username recorded in session variable U.
I'm noticing that file1.php is not persisting the login data, how do I do it?

Comment: How you do it is the way you've already written it, basically. So either it isn't really going into the if block and setting the session data (have you done a var_dump of the session at the end of file 1 to test?) or when you're accessing file2 it's not part of the same session for some reason.